# Create dictionary of a sqlalchemy query object in Pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am new to Python and Pyramid. In a test application I am using to learn more about Pyramid, I want to query a database and create a dictionary based on the results of a sqlalchemy query object and finally send the dictionary to the chameleon template.

So far I have the following code (which works fine), but I wanted to know if there is a better way to create my dictionary.

```
...
index = 0
clients = {}
q = self.request.params['q']
for client in DBSession.query(Client).filter(Client.name.like('%%%s%%' % q)).all():
    clients[index] = { "id": client.id, "name": client.name }
    index += 1
output = { "clients": clients }

return output
```

While learning Python, I found a nice way to create a list in a for loop statement like the following:

```
myvar = [user.name for user in users]
```

So, the other question I had: is there a similar 'one line' way like the above to create a dictionary of a sqlalchemy query object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well, yes, we can tighten this up a bit.

First, this pattern:

```
 index = 0
 for item in seq:
     frobnicate(index, item)
     item += 1
```

is common enough that there's a builtin function that does it automatically, `enumerate()`, used like this:

```
 for index, item in enumerate(seq):
     frobnicate(index, item)
```

*but*, I'm not sure you need it,  Associating things with an integer index starting from zero is the functionality of a list, you don't really need a dict for that; unless you want to have holes, or need some of the other special features of dicts, just do:

```
 stuff = []
 stuff.extend(seq)
```

when you're only interested in a small subset of the attributes of a database entity, it's a good idea to tell sqlalchemy to emit a query that returns only that:

```
 query = DBSession.query(Client.id, Client.name) \
                  .filter(q in Client.name)
```

In the above i've also shortened the `.name.like('%%%s%%' % q)` into just `q in name` since they mean the same thing (sqlalchemy expands it into the correct `LIKE` expression for you)

Queries constructed in this way return a [special thing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) that looks like a tuple, and can be easily turned into a dict by calling `_asdict()` on it:

so to put it all together

```
output = [row._asdict() for row in DBSession.query(Client.id, Client.name)
                                            .filter(q in Client.name)]
```

or, if you really desperately need it to be a dict, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
output = {index: row._asdict() 
          for index, row 
          in enumerate(DBSession.query(Client.id, Client.name)
                                .filter(q in Client.name))}
```

Comment: Wow, extremely helpful TokenMacGuy. I learned a lot from your detailed explanation. That is what I was looking for. Thanks man, appreciate it!

Comment: I had to use `(Client.name.contains(q))` since `(q in Client.name)` refused to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

@TokenMacGuy gave a nice and detailed answer to your question. However, I have a feeling you've asked a wrong question :)

You don't need to convert SQLALchemy objects to dictionaries before passing them to the template - that would be quite inconvenient. You can pass the result of a query as is and directly use SQLALchemy mapped objects in your template

```
q = self.request.params['q']
clients = DBSession.query(Client).filter(q in Client.name).all()
return {'clients': clients}
```

Comment: Ohh, you're right Sergey. I learned a lot from @TokenMacGuy answer but also your suggestion is great. I did it and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Sergey, you deserve a medal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a SqlAlchemy object into a dict, you can use this code:

```
def obj_to_dict(obj):
    return dict((col.name, getattr(obj, col.name)) for col in sqlalchemy_orm.class_mapper(obj.__class__).mapped_table.c)
```

there is another attribute of the mapped table that has the relationships in it , but the code gets dicey.

you don't need to cast an object into a dict for any of the template libraries, but if you decide to persist the data ( memcached, session, pickle, etc ) you'll either need to use dicts or write some code to 'merge' the persisted data back into the session.

a quick side note- if you render any of this data through json , you'll either need to have a custom json renderer that can handle datetime objects , or change the values in a function.